# Does perl have a syntax for return if defined?

Tags: perl

I'm looking to see if there is a perl shorthand, it seems there *always* is a perl shorthand, for returning if a value is defined.  I'm thinking about the common case where I need to check some hash to see if something exists, return if it does, otherwise generate the value.  I can do something like this:

```
$element = %seen_elements{$key};

return $element if defined $element;

#element doesn't exist so make it
return generate_element($key, $seen_elements);
```

Is there a shorthand for that second line, that avoids my having to reference element twice?  Most languages I wouldn't ask, but with so much syntactic sugar in perl I'm curious if they already made one for a minor but common usecase like this.

Comment: Do you realise that you usually don't have to explicitly create a hash element? You may be able to write just `return $seen_elements{$key}++` depending on what the hash is supposed to contain

Comment: Or `return $seen_elements{$key} //= 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, kind of. You can use `//`, the [logical defined or](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or).

```
sub foo {
  return $seen_elements{$key} // generate_element($key, $seen_elements);
}
```

This thing is like `||` (which is *or*), but tests for *definedness* instead of *truethiness*, so it will return an empty string, but not `undef`.

Comment: `//` is available in Perl 5.10.0 and up.

Comment: That should probably be `\%seen_elements`, but I realise that the OP's code is weird

Comment: @Borodin I was going to edit to tell OP that the `%seen_elements` in the first line is wrong, but I didn't even see that `$seen_elements` is passed. But anyway, since I wrote that, then saw the duplicate vote and hammered it, I should probably delete this answer anyway.

Comment: I don't think that duplicate vote is quite on the mark because of the involvement of `return`

Comment: @Borodin I think it doesn't matter what's on the left of it. The expression itself is what counts here, and that much transfer should be acceptable imho ;-)

Comment: I'm just thinking about the subject line. If the requirement was to abbreviate `return $element if defined $element` then it would need a different solution

Comment: I had considered // already, but wasn't certain it would work here.  I need to better figure out the order of operations as applied to //

Comment: @ds it will evaluate the LHS, and if that is undefined it will evaluate the RHS. It will then pass the value returned from the RHS operation or the LHS operation to the `return`.